# Store return value from function in array

Tags: c

I have very basic question, how can one store return value from a function in array.

Something like:

```
int func()
{
    return 8;
}
main()
{
    int *arry;
    arry[2] = func(); /* This is wrong but how to do it in C */
    printf("value of arry[2] is %d\n", arry[2]);
}

**EDIT** , Is there a way, this still works ?
```

Comment: If *course* that's how to do it in C.  You just need to make sure you use the right variable name: `int arr[5] != arry[2]`.  Q: Did your code compile, or did you get an "undefined" error?

Comment: Oops, not sure which version of code I was compiling and keep getting the segmentation fault on run :(

Comment: 1) The problem with the code  you first posted was a spelling error: you declared your variable `int arr[5]`, but you assigned to the variable `arry[2]`.  Whoops - typos happen :(  2) But the code in your update is *INCORRECT*. Declaring an array pointer `int *arry` is not sufficient.  You must *ALLOCATE MEMORY*.  Either `int array[8]` (generally preferred), or `int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*8)`.  Q: Does that make sense?  Q: Do you understand why failing to allocate memory results in a segmentation violation?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: `int arr[5];` should be `int arry[5];`.

Like this:

```
int func()
{
    return 8;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arry[5];
    arry[2] = func();
    printf("value of arry[2] is %d\n", arry[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that does work, you just have a typo (`arry`)

```
int func()
{
    return 8;
}

main()
{
    int arr[5];

    arr[2] = func();
    printf("%d\n", arr[2]);
}
```

prints `8`

Comment: Why don't you use prototypes?

Comment: ok, if you think you're better at checking number and types of arguments   than a compiler that's ok

Comment: I did not say that. I always use function prototypes for that very reason, but this question was not an illustration of a function prototype :)

Comment: @MatthewFollegot,  I just edited the question, this is where I was having problems when I run it.

Comment: @Milan `int *arry` initializes a pointer, not an array. You can index the second element using a pointer `*(arry + 2)`, but the initialization is still incorrect.